# Chromium: Page action not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make my first chrome extension and I want my extension to appear only on particular pages so am using `page_action`.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "First",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "First extension",

    "page_action": {

        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions" : [
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> Some other logic </body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
function check(tab_id, data, tab){

    if(tab.url.indexOf("google") > -1){
        chrome.pageAction.show(tab_id);
        alert("inside");

    }

    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(check);
};
```

Now, after loading the extension when I open `google.com` the icon doesn't appears and neither my javascript function get called.

So, where am I going wrong in this approach.

Chromium version  `24.0.1312.2 Ubuntu 12.04 (165266)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, you need to have a background script that listens tab updates. You should update your manifest like this:

```
{
    "name": "First",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "First extension",
    "background": { "scripts": ["test.js"] },
    ....
```

Also, you are setting the listener inside the function, so it's never being executed.

Move it out of the function and it should work

```
function check(tab_id, data, tab){
    if(tab.url.indexOf("google") > -1){
        chrome.pageAction.show(tab_id);
        alert("inside");

    }

};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(check);
```

Comment: I moved the function outside than also it is not working. I am not able to see any icon in the `address bar` when I open `google.com`.

Comment: Ok, i tried it on my computer and it looks like we need a background script to check tab updates. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Noob: The reason is `content script` have some limitations and one of them is [They cannot use chrome.* APIs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html).

Comment: @keune: It worked. Can you explain to me whats the difference between `content and background` scripts. If I want to do some `DOM manipulation` the relevant code should be inside backgroud or content script?

Comment: AFAIK, content scripts are for modifying the current page. It has access to DOM, so whenever you want to change the DOM you should do it in a content script. Background scripts have access to other browser features like opening new tabs, getting their urls etc. Check out official API pages: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html